# Google Drive : Delete FOLDERS older than 1 day

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, google-drive-api

I’m searching some help with AppScript. I want to delete any FOLDERS which are older than 1 day.

Here’s my situation I got a main folder that contains folders that contains files

```
> Main Folder
 >> Folder 1
       >>> File 1
       >>> File 2
       >>> File n
 >> Folder 2
       >>> File 1
 >> Folder n
```

I’d like to auto delete Folder n which are older than 1 day (and obviously files in it) 
Is it possible to make this with AppScript ?
I know there’s already that kind of script but it’s only working with files inside a folder

Best regards !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can't you adapt the script that deletes files?

Comment: I use that before https://blog.ss88.us/delete-files-from-google-drive-folders-after-x-days-apps-script/comment-page-1#comment-422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code puts the folder into the trash if the moment in time now is greater than the number of milliseconds in a day from the time that the folder was created.

```
function chkDateOfEveryFolder(parentFolderID) {
  var d,dateCreated,diffInMS,folder,folders,
      msInTimePeriod,nmbrOfDaysToChkFor,oneDayMS,parentFldr;

  /* Either pass in the ID of the parent folder to the function or set
   * the parent folder ID in the code below
  */

  nmbrOfDaysToChkFor = 1;//Number of days to check for as being older than

  if (!parentFolderID) {
    parentFolderID = "Enter the folder ID to start the search";
  }

  oneDayMS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;//number of milliseconds in one day

  if (nmbrOfDaysToChkFor > 1) {
    msInTimePeriod = oneDayMS * nmbrOfDaysToChkFor;
  } else {
    msInTimePeriod = oneDayMS;
  }

  d = new Date();

  parentFldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderID);

  folders = parentFldr.getFolders();//Get all folders within the parent folder

  while (folders.hasNext()) {//Is there another folder in the folder iterator
    folder = folders.next();
    dateCreated = folder.getDateCreated();

    //Logger.log(folder.getName() + " - Date:" + dateCreated);

    diffInMS = d.getTime() - dateCreated.getTime();

    //Logger.log('diffInMS: ' + diffInMS)

    if (diffInMS > msInTimePeriod) {
      folder.setTrashed(true);
      //Logger.log('folder is trashed: ' + folder.isTrashed());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit that script to avoid that eveything in my drive got deleted xD Like : I just place my main folder Id and it only checks folders in my main folder

Answer (score 0):

I got another problem

The anwser from Alan works well, when Im executing the script, it works, no problem.

I made a trigger with Google AppScript but the trigger is creating an error 25 
"Can not find the item corresponding to this identifier. You may not be able to access at chkDateOfEveryFolder(Code:25)"

Thanks

EDIT : `parentFldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderID);` 
this line (25) is the source of the problem

EDIT 2 : I removed this condition

```
if (!parentFolderID) {
    parentFolderID = "Enter the folder ID to start the search";
  }
```

To this

```
 parentFolderID = "Enter the folder ID to start the
```

And triggers are working now correctly